# Blender exported mesh extremely deformed

Tags: export, cloth-simulation, knife-tool

After exporting my mesh to FBX form to test out my sails in physx clothing, I noticed my mesh was terribly deformed. There were a lot of random spikes and abnormalities that appeared in the main hull part of the ship.

exported version
[image: exported file]

blender version:
[image: looks good]

In order to cut my holes in the main outside part of the ship I would Boolean it with a cylinder. Since the exterior was solidified, it has like 4 walls for some reason, so I just moved one interior side to overlap another to cover up the hole created around.

Sorry if i'm not making sense, this is my first blender project, and I really don't know what's going on. Will I have to redo the exterior?!?!?

Comment: Just to reiterate I am very very new to blender. I think the problem may be how I was covering the holes between the exterior and interior walls (simply moving them together to overlap).

Comment: Booleans are a lazy way of modelling and will always produce bad topology that will invariably lead to problems like the ones you show above. I'd advise re-modelling that hull using [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com)

Comment: Oh... It's just how somebody on youtube did it. Is there anyway to fix what I did with booleans? Anyway to undo them? I would rather not trash the hull and start again, as everything is aligned for it.

Comment: Did you apply the *Boolean* modifier? If not then just remove or disable it, they are non destructive, that is the big advantage of modifiers. Otherwise no easy fix you will probably have to start over, unless the damage is localized and you can erase just the affected faces and rebuild from there

Comment: Yeah I applied it all, but the question still stands: Why does blender render everything perfectly but exported version is so messed up?

Comment: I have no clue, without looking at your file or mesh topology it is a blind guess. Most likely is because Blender supports NGons, which are faces with more than 4 sides, and most other applications don't really like those. Bottom line here is the same: **use proper topology**. Avoid Booleans, avoid NGons, avoid Triangles, prefer a mesh with quad dominant topology. Follow the guide linked above.

Comment: So should I not have circular openings in the hull, only square?

Comment: Use a subdivision surface modifier

Answer (score 0):

To solve this try to add a *Triangulate Modifier* and apply it. If this doesn't work well I don't know what will.