# Blender export fbx file holes in mesh deformed

Tags: modeling, export, .fbx

After learning that booleans were apparently "bad" in my past question of this same problem, I decided to learn to use the knife tool instead to cut windows and doors in my ship.

Old thread: [Blender exported mesh extremely deformed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80916/blender-exported-mesh-extremely-deformed)

Unfortunately, despite using the knife tool and everything looking allright in Blender, when exporting to fbx and using in ClothingToolCHECKED of the Nvidia apex cloth simulation, the cut outs were extremely deformed. This is the second time this has happened, even though I'm not using booleans!

This is very frustrating, as it took me a long time to redo the parts of my ship that had booleans in them.

Here are images of what I mean:

Blender:

[image: looks fine]

fbx export:

[image: wtf]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the faces with more than 4 edges (ngons), in your case, most of them have 6 edges.

[image: ngons]

What you can do is select all the faces around the windows, the press CTRL+T to convert them to triangles and then ALT+J to convert them to quads.

[image: to_tris_to_quads]

Notice how I set Max Face Angle and Max Sharp Angle to 180º.

You also should remove unnecessary vertices like these:
[image]
By pressing ALT+M to merge them before converting the ngons to tris then to quads.

Comment: Wow, this is so amazing, exactly what I am looking for, you are a hero, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to FBX but it look like you have some inverted normals or overlapping faces. It would be easier to help you with some screenshot of your topology or the blend file.

Comment: I created a link (it is the blend file), hopefully this works: https://ufile.io/vhqr8